# How to reset FreeTextBox without a button cause it seems the precious text is still contain

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
 <FTB:FreeTextBox id="NOI_DUNG" runat="server" 
            EditorBorderColorDark="DarkGray" EditorBorderColorLight="DarkGray" 
            Width="100%" GutterBorderColorDark="Gray" GutterBorderColorLight="White" 
            ToolbarStyleConfiguration="OfficeMac" AutoGenerateToolbarsFromString="True" 
            ToolbarImagesLocation="InternalResource" 
            JavaScriptLocation="InternalResource" 
            ButtonImagesLocation="InternalResource" 
            ImageGalleryUrl="aspnet_client/ftb.imagegallery.aspx?rif=/imagespath/&cif=../upload/imagesupload/"
             ImageGalleryPath="/upload/imagesupload/" SupportFolder="../aspnet_client/FreeTextBox/" />
```

I also have a table in SQL database:

```
NOTICE(num,title,content [allow null])
```

I have 1 textbox to input: `title`, and 1 FreeTextBox to input `content`.

The first time, I input both `title` and `content`->click button "INSERT"--> work fine

The twice, I just imput only `title` and I let the `content` empty-->click button "INSERT"-->the field `content` in Database is auto filled with the old content of the first input time.

I really dont know why. The only way, I think I shoul Reset(clean) the textfield of FreeTextBox when page load?